# Cursor position set

Tags: c#, cursor, mouseevent

I'm having an issue with the 'Cursor.Position' property.. I am trying to make a cursor which moves in blocks of 20 within a panel, so I can place blocks. Like those 2d game designer block placing tools.

```
int mPosX = 20;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X > mPosX)
    {
        mPosX += 20;
        Cursor.Position = new Point(e.X + 20, e.Y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor.Position.Y <> e.Y

e.y is relative, while Cursor.Position.Y is global

you could use something like:

```
            if (e.X > mPosX)
            {
                mPosX += 20;
                Point p = Cursor.Position;
                p.X += (20 - Cursor.Position.X % 20);
                Cursor.Position = p;
            }
```